# Using DataContracts for Complex types in WCF

Tags: wcf

```
[Operation Contract]
public ET Get_ET()
{
   return  ET_Select();  //ET_Select()  returns a complex type
}

[Data Contract]
public class ET
{
    [Data Member]
    public int PIN {get;set;}

    [Data Member]
    public int Name {get;set;}
}
```

In the above sample code., ET_Select() store procedure is returning complex type., but i want to cast that as "ET" which is a data contract.
Please guide me how to use data contract in case of complex types.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the complex type look like (i.e., can you show the code for the complex type)?

Comment: storeproceudre returning a view., so i have not binded to an entity instead i have given as complex type